# Create a score in a quiz app

Tags: ios, swift

I've created a quiz app from a youtube tutorial. Now I want to add a score in order for the player to view it. The app works by adding 3 points if you choose option a, 2 if you choose b and 1 if you choose c.

But whenever I change questions, the score value goes back to 0, how can I fix it?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var Question: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var answer1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var answer2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var answer3: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var nextquestion: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var results: UILabel!
    var questionnumber = Int()
    var total = Int()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        questionnumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(15))
        total = 0

        switch questionnumber {
            case 0:
                Question.text = "Aproximadamente, ¿cuántas veces al día usas el coche?"
                answer1.setTitle("3 veces", for: UIControlState.normal)
                answer2.setTitle("5 veces", for: UIControlState.normal)
                answer3.setTitle("+ 6 veces", for: UIControlState.normal)
                break
            case 1:
                Question.text = "¿Cuánto te tardas bañándote?"
                answer1.setTitle("5-10 minutos", for: UIControlState.normal)
                answer2.setTitle("10-15 minutos", for: UIControlState.normal)
                answer3.setTitle("+ 15 minutos", for: UIControlState.normal)
                break
            case 2:
                Question.text = "¿Separas la basura?"
                answer1.setTitle("Sí", for: UIControlState.normal)
                answer2.setTitle("De vez en cuando", for: UIControlState.normal)
                answer3.setTitle("No", for: UIControlState.normal)
                break
            case 3:
                Question.text = "¿Dejas correr el agua cuando te lavas los dientes?"
                answer1.setTitle("Sí", for: UIControlState.normal)
                answer2.setTitle("Algunas veces", for: UIControlState.normal)
                answer3.setTitle("No", for: UIControlState.normal)
                break
            case 4:
                Question.text = "¿Lavas tu coche con cubeta o manguera?"
                answer1.setTitle("Cubeta", for: UIControlState.normal)
                answer2.setTitle("Manguera", for: UIControlState.normal)
                answer3.setTitle("", for: UIControlState.normal)
                break
            case 5:
                Question.text = "¿Reciclas o reutilizas el papel?"
                answer1.setTitle("Sí", for: UIControlState.normal)
                answer2.setTitle("Algunas veces", for: UIControlState.normal)
                answer3.setTitle("No", for: UIControlState.normal)
                break
            case 6:
                Question.text = "¿Usas las bolsas ecológicas en el supermercado?"
    answer1.setTitle("Sí", for: UIControlState.normal)
    answer2.setTitle("De vez en cuando", for: UIControlState.normal)
    answer3.setTitle("No", for: UIControlState.normal)
        break
    case 7:
    Question.text = "¿Pones las pilas en contenedores especiales?"
    answer1.setTitle("Sí", for: UIControlState.normal)
    answer2.setTitle("Algunas veces", for: UIControlState.normal)
    answer3.setTitle("No", for: UIControlState.normal)
        break
    case 8:
    Question.text = "¿Afinas tu coche cuando te toca?"
    answer1.setTitle("Sí", for: UIControlState.normal)
    answer2.setTitle("De vez en cuando", for: UIControlState.normal)
    answer3.setTitle("No", for: UIControlState.normal)
        break
    case 9:
    Question.text = "¿Reutilizas las botellas de agua?"
    answer1.setTitle("Sí", for: UIControlState.normal)
    answer2.setTitle("Algunas veces", for: UIControlState.normal)
    answer3.setTitle("No", for: UIControlState.normal)
        break
    case 10:
    Question.text = "¿Qué tan seguido usas la lavadora?"
    answer1.setTitle("1-2 veces por semana", for: UIControlState.normal)
    answer2.setTitle("3-4 veces por semana", for: UIControlState.normal)
    answer3.setTitle("+ 5 veces por semana", for: UIControlState.normal)
        break
    case 11:
    Question.text = "¿Utilizas popote cuando tomas líquidos?"
    answer1.setTitle("Sí", for: UIControlState.normal)
    answer2.setTitle("De vez en cuando", for: UIControlState.normal)
    answer3.setTitle("No", for: UIControlState.normal)
        break
    case 12:
    self.Question.text = "¿Tiras basura en la calle/mar?"
    self.answer1.setTitle("Sí", for: UIControlState.normal)
    answer2.setTitle("Algunas veces", for: UIControlState.normal)
    answer3.setTitle("No", for: UIControlState.normal)
        break
    case 13:
    Question.text = "¿Utilizas calentador solar en tu casa?"
    answer1.setTitle("Sí", for: UIControlState.normal)
    answer2.setTitle("No", for: UIControlState.normal)
    answer3.setTitle("", for: UIControlState.normal)
        break
    case 14:
    Question.text = "¿Dejas luces encendidas cuando no es necesario?"
    answer1.setTitle("Sí", for: UIControlState.normal)
    answer2.setTitle("Algunas veces", for: UIControlState.normal)
    answer3.setTitle("No", for: UIControlState.normal)
        break
    default:
        break
    }

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // Add a target to your button

    // Create the method you want to call (see target before)


    @IBAction func answer1pressed(_ sender: Any) {
        total = total + 3
        results.text = "Total:\(total)"
    }

    @IBAction func answer2pressed(_ sender: Any) {
        total = total + 2
        results.text = "Total:\(total)"
    }

    @IBAction func answer3pressed(_ sender: Any) {
        total = total + 1
        results.text = "Total:\(total)"
    }


    @IBAction func nextquestion(_ sender: Any) {
        viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are set the value of total in viewDidLoad method, because you calling this method when nextQuestion button pressed, the total value will be 0 again. You need to move the equals 0 outside the viewDidLoad method. For example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{

@IBOutlet weak var Question: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var answer1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var answer2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var answer3: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var nextquestion: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var results: UILabel!

var questionnumber = Int()
var total: Int = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    questionnumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(15))
    switch questionnumber {
    case 0:
        Question.text = "Aproximadamente, ¿cuántas veces al día usas el coche?"
        answer1.setTitle("3 veces", for: UIControlState.normal)
        answer2.setTitle("5 veces", for: UIControlState.normal)
        answer3.setTitle("+ 6 veces", for: UIControlState.normal)
        break
    case 1:
        Question.text = "¿Cuánto te tardas bañándote?"
        answer1.setTitle("5-10 minutos", for: UIControlState.normal)
        answer2.setTitle("10-15 minutos", for: UIControlState.normal)
        answer3.setTitle("+ 15 minutos", for: UIControlState.normal)
        break
    case 2:
        Question.text = "¿Separas la basura?"
        answer1.setTitle("Sí", for: UIControlState.normal)
        answer2.setTitle("De vez en cuando", for: UIControlState.normal)
        answer3.setTitle("No", for: UIControlState.normal)
        break
    case 3:
        Question.text = "¿Dejas correr el agua cuando te lavas los dientes?"
        answer1.setTitle("Sí", for: UIControlState.normal)
        answer2.setTitle("Algunas veces", for: UIControlState.normal)
        answer3.setTitle("No", for: UIControlState.normal)
        break
    case 4:
        Question.text = "¿Lavas tu coche con cubeta o manguera?"
        answer1.setTitle("Cubeta", for: UIControlState.normal)
        answer2.setTitle("Manguera", for: UIControlState.normal)
        answer3.setTitle("", for: UIControlState.normal)
        break
    case 5:
        Question.text = "¿Reciclas o reutilizas el papel?"
        answer1.setTitle("Sí", for: UIControlState.normal)
        answer2.setTitle("Algunas veces", for: UIControlState.normal)
        answer3.setTitle("No", for: UIControlState.normal)
        break
    case 6:
        Question.text = "¿Usas las bolsas ecológicas en el supermercado?"
        answer1.setTitle("Sí", for: UIControlState.normal)
        answer2.setTitle("De vez en cuando", for: UIControlState.normal)
        answer3.setTitle("No", for: UIControlState.normal)
        break
    case 7:
        Question.text = "¿Pones las pilas en contenedores especiales?"
        answer1.setTitle("Sí", for: UIControlState.normal)
        answer2.setTitle("Algunas veces", for: UIControlState.normal)
        answer3.setTitle("No", for: UIControlState.normal)
        break
    case 8:
        Question.text = "¿Afinas tu coche cuando te toca?"
        answer1.setTitle("Sí", for: UIControlState.normal)
        answer2.setTitle("De vez en cuando", for: UIControlState.normal)
        answer3.setTitle("No", for: UIControlState.normal)
        break
    case 9:
        Question.text = "¿Reutilizas las botellas de agua?"
        answer1.setTitle("Sí", for: UIControlState.normal)
        answer2.setTitle("Algunas veces", for: UIControlState.normal)
        answer3.setTitle("No", for: UIControlState.normal)
        break
    case 10:
        Question.text = "¿Qué tan seguido usas la lavadora?"
        answer1.setTitle("1-2 veces por semana", for: UIControlState.normal)
        answer2.setTitle("3-4 veces por semana", for: UIControlState.normal)
        answer3.setTitle("+ 5 veces por semana", for: UIControlState.normal)
        break
    case 11:
        Question.text = "¿Utilizas popote cuando tomas líquidos?"
        answer1.setTitle("Sí", for: UIControlState.normal)
        answer2.setTitle("De vez en cuando", for: UIControlState.normal)
        answer3.setTitle("No", for: UIControlState.normal)
        break
    case 12:
        self.Question.text = "¿Tiras basura en la calle/mar?"
        self.answer1.setTitle("Sí", for: UIControlState.normal)
        answer2.setTitle("Algunas veces", for: UIControlState.normal)
        answer3.setTitle("No", for: UIControlState.normal)
        break
    case 13:
        Question.text = "¿Utilizas calentador solar en tu casa?"
        answer1.setTitle("Sí", for: UIControlState.normal)
        answer2.setTitle("No", for: UIControlState.normal)
        answer3.setTitle("", for: UIControlState.normal)
        break
    case 14:
        Question.text = "¿Dejas luces encendidas cuando no es necesario?"
        answer1.setTitle("Sí", for: UIControlState.normal)
        answer2.setTitle("Algunas veces", for: UIControlState.normal)
        answer3.setTitle("No", for: UIControlState.normal)
        break
    default:
        break
    }

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


@IBAction func answer1pressed(_ sender: Any) {
    total = total + 3
    results.text = "Total:\(total)"
}
@IBAction func answer2pressed(_ sender: Any) {
    total = total + 2
    results.text = "Total:\(total)"
}
@IBAction func answer3pressed(_ sender: Any) {
    total = total + 1
    results.text = "Total:\(total)"
}


@IBAction func nextquestion(_ sender: Any)
{
    viewDidLoad()
}
}
```

This part is the most important:

```
var total: Int = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   questionnumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(15))
   switch questionnumber {
   case 0:
```